# Proguard: there were 210 duplicate class definitions?

Tags: android, warnings, proguard

Eclipse shows warnings below, it seems it has something with proguard. But my project can be signed in other computer, and I did signed it before! what's wrong? how to fix it?

Note: there were 210 duplicate class definitions.
You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
Warning: can't write resource [META-INF/MANIFEST.MF] (Duplicate zip entry [android-support-v4.jar:META-INF/MANIFEST.MF])
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. -injar is needed. @see: [Why Eclipse Can't Write Resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13356595/why-eclipse-cant-write-resource)

EDIT: FInally, I found: It is not compatible with Astrill（VPN）, I force closed astrill process and problems gone.